# Failed to load resource when setting server.servlet.context-path

Tags: spring-boot-admin

When I set the Context path of my Spring Boot Admin application `server.servlet.context-path=/bootadmin`

When I go to [http://localhost:8080/bootadmin](http://localhost:8080/bootadmin/) I hit 404 errors loading static files like CSS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's already raised here:
https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/804